# Can we access Bloc without Passing Buildcontext param

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am migrating to GetX to Bloc, in `GetController` we don't need `BuildContext` to call controller, so is there any way to Provide the Context to the bloc class from `BlocProvider` and we get bloc without providing buildContext like  for example:

```
BlocProvider(
create: (context) => TestBloc(context),
),
```

```
class TestBloc extends Bloc<TestEvent, TestState> {
  final BuildContext context;

  TestBloc(this.context) : super(const TestInitial(false)) {
    on<TestEvent1>((event, emit) {});
  }
  static TestBloc bloc() => BlocProvider.of<TestBloc>(context); //<--- Instance members can't be accessed from a static method.
// I want to access bloc without BuildContext
}
```

Calling the bloc

```
final testBloc = TestBloc.bloc();
```

I need this because i want to navigate the user from notification tap and there we don't have

```
BuildContext
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the class. Here it named as NavigationService

   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   ```
    class NavigationService { 
      static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = 
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
    }
   ```
2. Set the navigatorKey property of MaterialApp in the main.dart

   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
   navigatorKey: NavigationService.navigatorKey,
   )
   }
3. Great! Now you can use anywhere you want e.g.

   print("---print context: ${NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext}");

now you in your project like following

```
 static TestBloc bloc() => BlocProvider.of<TestBloc>(NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext);
```

Comment: I am using `Material.router()` they don't have `navigatorKey:` property

Comment: Hello Fahad if you using go router you will add like this GoRouter(
navigatorKey: navigatorKey,)